# Unobserved exception was rethrown despite awaiting the Task and catching Exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, xamarin.ios, async-await

I have code that catches all exceptions that are thrown by a server call as follows:

```
    new public Task SaveAsync()
    {
        return ServerException.Wrap(base.SaveAsync);
    }
```

Where ServerException.Wrap looks like:

```
    public static async Task<T> Wrap<T>(Func<Task<T>> func)
    {
        try
        {
            return await func();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // This is an internal error that shouldn't happen.
            throw new ServerException(ex);
        }
    }

    public static async Task Wrap(Func<Task> func)
    {
        await Wrap(async () =>
            {
                await func();
                return true;
            });
    }
```

And then I have a function that calls SaveAsync as follows:

```
        try
        {
            await problem.SaveAsync();
        }
        catch (ServerException ex)
        {
            Logger.LogException("Error saving problem.", ex);
        }
```

I have some internal error that generates an exception which I catch in the above line and then it gets logged as follows:

> 2015-10-20 11:20:44.502 [Line 99] Error saving problem. (Exception:
>   Exceptions.ServerException:  ---> System.ArgumentException: An item
>   with the same key has already been added.   at
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException (ExceptionResource resource)
>   [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/1977/2c66d2fe/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/throwhelper.cs:74

However a few seconds later I get an unhanded exception warning that gets logged:

> 2015-10-20 11:21:16.352 Warning: Unhandled exception:
>   System.AggregateException: A Task's exception(s) were not observed
>   either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As
>   a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer
>   thread. ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has
>   already been added.   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException
>   (ExceptionResource resource) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/1977/2c66d2fe/source/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/throwhelper.cs:74

Why do I get the second unobserved exception, even though I am catching and handling the first exception? This exception seems to be thrown by my ServerException.Wrap method.

I am using MonoTouch.

Comment: Are you sure this is all the relevant code?

Comment: This is the simplified version. What other part of the code do you need?

Comment: The part where a task isn't awaited :) How does `SaveAsync` look?

Comment: You mean `base.SaveAsync`? I don't have code for that. That's a library I call. My `SaveAsync` is at the beginning. There is a bunch of code around, but none of that has anything to do with Tasks. Afaik the task is awaited.

Comment: @KostubDeshmukh: Please post minimal, *reproducible* code. That way we can see the error, too.

Comment: I am experiencing similar issue with MonoTouch. Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: @DavidRiha no, I did not find a solution.

Answer (score -2):

You need to explicitly set the exception to observed.

For that, you need to subscribe to the `TaskScheduler`'s `UnobservedTaskException` event, and set it explicitly to `observed` (call SetObserved() on it).

See here:

[UnobservedTaskException being throw...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831844/unobservedtaskexception-being-throw-but-it-is-handled-by-a-taskscheduler-unobser)

EDIT:
Of course, you can also just catch `AggregateException` as well, or use ContinueWith() to observe and resume the task.

See the bottom of the official documentation:

[Exception Handling (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Why should it be unobserved to begin with?